# Convert for loop to recursive basic method

Tags: c++, recursion

I tried to covert this for loop to a recursive one, please tell me if its correct

NORMAL

```
void countDown(int n){
for (int i=n; i>0; i--) {
cout << “Time is up\n”;
}
```

RECURSIVE

```
int countDown(int n, int i)
{
if (n == i) return "time is up";
return countDown(n-1,i+n);
}
```

Comment: It all depends on how you call the function.

Comment: You cannot return both a string, when it is expecting an integer to be returned.

Comment: returning string? from an `int` function

Comment: crap i didnt realise that

Comment: Please include sample input and output to clarify your problem.

Comment: No, it's not correct.  Your compiler should fail on the first sample (at the `“` character) and on the second sample (returning a `const char*` from a function declared as returning `int`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a string when you actually want to display it. Your return type should then be void.

Also, I think you are making it a bit too complicated for what you want to do. Your test should be to check if i is greater than 0. If it's the case, then you display your message, and call the same function by removing 1 to i. Else, you just do nothing: i is equal to 0, so you exit the function.

```
void countDown(int i)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        cout << "time is up\n";
        countDown(i-1);
    }
}
```

And you call that same function by giving the value n to i.

Now your logic sounds strange in your first function. You are showing "time is up" at every iteration, while you probably just want to wait for n iterations, and then to show it when you are out of your for section. What you really want to achieve is probably this:

```
void countDown(int n)
{
    for (int i=n; i>0; i--)
    {
        // Do anything like showing the countdown or something.
    }

    cout << “time is up\n”;
}
```

And in recursive:

```
void countDown(int i)
{
    if (i == 0)
        cout << "time is up\n";
    else 
        countDown(i-1);
}
```

Every time you call the function, you check if your countdown reached 0. If it is the case, you display the message explaining that the time is up. Else, you recursively call the function, decreasing i by 1.

Comment: It will print `time is up` on every recursion. `cout` should be inside `if(i==0)`

Comment: @Sniper I'd agree with you in normal times, but there I'm just translating the first code section of OP into a recursive function, as he is showing it for every iteration in his for section. I edited my answer to show to the OP what he is probably wanting to achieve though.

Answer (score 0):

I would return a string, and only pass a single parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char* countDown(int n)
{
  if (n == 0) {
    return "Time is up";
  }

  return countDown(n-1);
}

int main(void) {
  cout << countDown(10) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete tested to work logical code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void countDown(int n)
{
 for (int i=n; i>0; i--)
 {
  cout << i  << "\n";
 }

 cout << "\nTime is up\n";
}

void countDownRec(int n)
{
  if(n == 0)
  {
   cout << "\nTime is up\n";
   return;
  }

  cout << n  << "\n";
  countDownRec(n-1);
}

int main()
{
 countDown(5);

 cout<<"\n";

 countDownRec(5);

 return 0;
}
```